# Numerical methods to minimize a matrix function

Tags: matrices, optimization, reference-request, numerical-optimization, matrix-norms

I'm faced with the problem 
\begin{align*}
\min_{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}}\left\{f(A)+\lambda\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert_{S_p}^p\right\},
\end{align*}
where $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some generic matrix function, $\lambda>0$ is a fixed constant and $\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert_{S_p}$ is the $p$-Schatten *norm* of $A$ defined as 
\begin{align*}
\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert_{S_p} = \left(\sum_j|\sigma_j(A)|^p\right)^{1/p},
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_j(A)$ are the singular values of $A$ (its a norm ony when $p\geq 1$; when $p=1$, is the nuclear norm). There are some special cases when the problem has an explicit and unique solution. For example, if $p=1$ and $f(A)=g(A):=\lvert\lvert A-X\rvert\rvert_F^2$ for some fixed $X$, where $\lvert\lvert \cdot\rvert\rvert_F$ is the Frobenius norm. Also, there are papers that describe numerical method to solve the problem when $f=g$ and $p<1$.

My question is: Do you know some *generic* algorithm to solve this problem for any $f$ and any $p$? I'm specially interested in the case $p<1$, when the Schatten norm is not convex (and not a norm).

Comment: Give your choice of $f$, it seems that we could at least look for critical points.  That being said, non-convex optimization for matrix functions is generally very difficult.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm working with $f(A) = ||H(A)-X||_F^2$, where $H:R^{n,m}\to R^{(n+m),(n+m)}$ is the Hermitian dilation of $A$, defined for example in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353819/eigenvalues-of-hermitian-dilation-of-any-square-matrix.

Comment: When in doubt, one can try inexact Newton-CG with trust region globalization. You will have to differentiate through the singular value decomposition, but this is doable.

Comment: Here is a paper about differentiating through the SVD: https://j-towns.github.io/papers/svd-derivative.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\theta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{\|A\|_{S_p}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The $p^{th}$ power of the Schatten p-norm can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\A^p &= \trace{(A^TA)^{\frac p2}} \\
}$$
and this leads to a rather simple formula for its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\|A\|_{S_p}^p}{A} &= pA\LR{A^TA}^{\b},\qquad \b=\fracLR{p-2}2 \\
}$$
Given the cost function
$$\eqalign{
h \;=\; f \;+\; \l\A^p \\
}$$
Assuming that you know the gradient of $f$,
the gradient of this cost function is simply
$$\eqalign{
\grad{h}{A} \;=\; \grad{f}{A} \;+\; \l pA\LR{A^TA}^{\b} \;\;\doteq\;\; g(A) \\
}$$
Now you can use *any* gradient-based method
(i.e. conjugate gradients, Barzilai-Borwein, etc)
to minimize $h.\;$ The basic iteration will look something like this
$$\eqalign{
A_{k+1} &= A_k - \a_k\,g(A_k) \\
}$$
where $\a_k$ is the step-length for the chosen method, and $k$ is the iteration counter.